# manage forms with Dynamic Fields Group

Tags: php, html, forms

I have form like this. I want add dynamic multi group fileds (user create fields groups if needs)...

currently I do it this way:

```
<form>

<!-- group fileds 1 -->
<input type="text" id="input1">
<select id="slect1"></select/>

<!-- group fileds 2 -->
<input type="text" id="input2">
<select id="select2"></select/>
.
.
.
<!-- group fileds n -->
<input type="text" id="inputn">
<select id="selectn"></select/>
</form>
```

But manage is hard,specially in php server.

can you recommend me a better way?

for example this is my idia:

I create one hidden input.

read input&select via jquery,convert it to a long json string,and write it to hidden input.

then in server side, I only read that hidden input and parse json.

it seems complex

how do you manage these type of forms?

Comment: Carefully and with a bit of practice, trial and error

Comment: But seriously I for one am not sure what you are askiing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexes after inputs' names. This work will give you an array at the server side, in `$_POST['input']` and `$_POST['select']`:

```
<form method='post' action='sth.php'>

<!-- group fileds 1 -->
<input type="text" name="input[0]">
<select name="select[0]"></select/>

<!-- group fileds 2 -->
<input type="text" name="input[1]">
<select name="select[1]"></select/>

<!-- group fileds 3 -->
<input type="text" name="input[2]">
<select name="select[2]"></select/>

</form>
```